# Is there PIL equivalence in ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, python-imaging-library

The [Python Image Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) is so great than I want to use it in Ruby. Is there any colon/port/wrapper/equivalence? I know `RMagick` but it seems very heavy and has a sharp learning curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [devil for Ruby](http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2009/10/14/the-devil-image-library-for-ruby/). It is not a PIL port/wrapper but seems to be decently featured, is fast and lightweight. Its learning curve doesn't seem very sharp. Unfortunately the documentation is not very comprehensive.